# Poller is not running, file script/poller not found. Activities are not updated, repos not created

Tags: git, self-hosting, gitorious

i've updated gitorious from 2.x to 3. After some trouble i'm able to pull, push etc.. But the activity stream is not updated and repositories are not created ("Your new repository is being created" persists).

```
> ./script/diagnose
Both MergeRequest and its :status machine have defined a different default for "status". Use only one or the other for defining defaults to avoid unexpected behaviors.
everything healthy?                          false
git user ok?                                 true
gitorius front web page is up?               false
rails process present & owned by git user?   true
atleast one gitorious account present?       true
repo base dir present, owned by git user?    true
tarball dirs present, owned by git user?     true
git user has ~/.ssh/authorized_keys file?    true
ssh deamon is up?                            true
git daemon is up?                            true
poller is up?                                false
mysql is up?                                 true
ultrasphinx is up?                           true
queue service is up?                         true
memcached is up?                             true
enough disk free?                            true
enough RAM free?                             true
healthy cpu load average?                    true


uptime:
 13:40:41 up 81 days, 17:17,  1 user,  load average: 1.45, 0.76, 0.37


free:
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          2048       1353        694          0          0        289
-/+ buffers/cache:       1063        984
Swap:            0          0          0


vmstat:
procs -----------memory---------- ---swap-- -----io---- --system-- -----cpu-----
 r  b   swpd   free   buff  cache   si   so    bi    bo   in   cs us sy id wa st
 0  0      0 711344      0 296864    0    0     4     7    0    5 14  3 83  0  0


df:
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/vzfs        25G   15G   11G  59% /
none            1.0G  4.0K  1.0G   1% /dev
```

and the poller script doesnt exists:

```
> RAILS_ENV=production script/poller start                                                                                       
zsh: datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden: script/poller
```

My files:

```
> ls script bin                                                                                         
bin:
bundle   create-user  git-proxy      micro-tests  rake               restart  search_engine  snapshot  update-ui                  varnish
console  gitorious    gts-whats-new  migrate      repo_housekeeping  restore  setup.rb       unicorn   upgrade-gitorious3-config

script:
create_admin  destroy_invalid_events  git-daemon        git-proxy     regenerate_assets    server                          suspend_user          upgrade_to
create_user   diagnose                gitorious         rails         regenerate_ssh_keys  shard_git_repositories_by_hash  test_ldap_connection
create_wikis  fixup_hooks             gitorious-config  rake-wrapper  restart_unicorn      snapshot                        undo_last_upgrade
```

Where is the poller script and how to start this in v3? Is this the reason for the problems?

Comment: Working on these problems as well.  Will post findings if I make progress, please do the same.

Comment: I'm not a dev on the project, but maybe they forgot to remove that line in the diagnostic.

I got our install upgraded (finally) and still have some rendering issues.  However, I am able to create projects and repo's without the poller running.  "Everything Healthy" and "Front Web Page" still show false for me.  If it helps, nothing worked until I had my frontend apache serve the site on port 80, as well as the SSL one.

Comment: @JustinSmith The "Front Web Page"-status problem will may be solved with your port 80 suggestion... but the poller will not run, right?

Comment: My issue was dangling records from the upgraded DB, see: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gitorious/9XFQmY2Jq04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the answer in [my Google Groups post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gitorious/bn6CWGB8O-8) you can (or not) start poller via

`sudo service resque-worker start`

if you have installed gitorious via ce-installer. In my case the setup is a weird mix up with ce-installer and custom repair work. So this does not work for me (service unknown).

But the `resque-worker` leads to `/etc/init/resque-worker.conf`.

If you look inside `/etc/init/resque-worker.conf`:

```
description "Run a Resque worker on all queues"
author "Marius Mårnes Mathiesen <marius@gitorious.com>"

start on started rc RUNLEVEL=[35]
stop on runlevel [06]

env PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin
env QUEUE=*
env PIDFILE=/var/www/gitorious/app/tmp/pids/resque-worker1.pid

exec /usr/local/bin/chruby-exec ruby-1.9.3-p448 -- /var/www/gitorious/app/bin/rake resque:work
respawn
```

Now i've temporary executed `QUEUE=* /var/www/gitorious/app/bin/rake resque:work` which started inside the current terminal.

According to the `./script/diagnose` the poller is now running and I'm receiving notification mails and the activity stream is updated.

<s>The last step (hopefully) is to repair the script, to run it as service. I will update this post ASAP.</s>

In `ce-installer/upgrade.sh`, line 71 (function start-gitorious) I've found the solution to start the `resque-worker`. Just type:

`start resque-worker`

<s>(not `sudo service resque-worker start`)</s>!

Comment: Does this fix the "false" report from the diagnostic?

Comment: Yes, this fixes the false report, just for the "poller".